# If $R$ is a Householder reflection matrix, show that $(R+I)$ is always singular

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $R$ is a Householder reflection matrix, show that $(R+I)$ is always singular, and that $(R + \lambda I)$ is invertible for any $\lambda \not\in \{1, −1\}$. The Householder matrix is defined as $R = I - 2vv^T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $R = I - 2vv^T$ (for a unit vector $v$), show that $(R + I)v = 0$.

---

Regarding the second part of the question: one approach is to consider eigenvalues. The eigenvalues of $R$ are the values of $\lambda$ for which $R + \lambda I$ is invertible. To see that $\pm 1$ are the only eigenvalues, it suffices to note that $\operatorname{span}\{v\}$ and $\operatorname{span}\{v\}^\perp$ form a complete decomposition of $\Bbb R^n$ into eigenspaces.

Another approach: I claim that for $\lambda \notin \{\pm 1\}$, $R + \lambda I$ has an inverse of the form $a I + b vv^T$. Indeed, note that $R + \lambda I = (1 + \lambda) I - 2vv^T$. We have
$$
(a I + bvv^T)((1 + \lambda)I - 2vv^T) = 1\cdot I + 0 \cdot vv^T \iff\\
[(1 + \lambda)a] I + [(1 + \lambda)b - 2a - 2b]vv^T \iff\\
\begin{cases}
(\lambda + 1) a = 1\\
(\lambda - 1)b - 2a = 0
\end{cases}
\iff\\
\begin{cases}
a = \frac 1{\lambda + 1}\\
b =  \frac{2a}{\lambda - 1} = \frac{2}{\lambda^2 - 1}.
\end{cases}
$$
So indeed: if $\lambda \notin \{\pm 1\}$, then $R + \lambda I$ is invertible.

Comment: $(R+I)v = 2(I - vv^T)v = 2(v - vv^Tv) = 2(v - v) = 0$. Since $v$ is a unit vector: $v^Tv = |v|_2^2 = 1$. Therefore, $(R+I)$ is a singular matrix. What about the invertibility? $(R+aI) = (I - 2vv^T + aI) = (1+a)I - 2vv^T$.  I should show that $null(R+aI) = 0$. Let $x \in R^{n},$ $(R+aI)x = (1+a)x - 2v^txv$. Geometrically, it is the sum of the projection of the vector $x$, along the hyperplane with unit norm $v$, with some multiple of the vector $x$.

Comment: @user13 If you are asking a question, then I do not understand what the question is

Comment: I was asking about the second part of the question i.e. $(R+aI)$ is invertible for any $a \not \in \{1,-1\}$. I just wrote some of my thoughts about it.

Comment: @user13 I see, that makes sense now. I'll add something about the second part